# How to check the sibling to output correct data after grouping?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to group by Reference below. XML input file

```
<root>
<row>
<Company>HHH</Company>
<Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>
<Reference>12345</Reference>
<Assignment>54321</Assignment>
</row>
<row>
<Company>HHH</Company>
<Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>
<Reference>12345</Reference>
<Assignment>321</Assignment>
</row>
<row>
<Company>HHH</Company>
<Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>
<Reference>12345</Reference>
<Assignment>311</Assignment>
</row>
<root>
<row>
<Company>SSS</Company>
<Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>
<Reference>67890</Reference>
<Assignment>78968</Assignment>
</row>
<row>
<Company>SSS</Company>
<Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>
<Reference>67890</Reference>
<Assignment>98769</Assignment>
</row>
```

Desired Output where Posting Key 40 is inside the row, and posting key 15 are inside the details within that row.

```
<root>
    <row>
    <Company>HHH</Company>
    <Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>
    <Reference>12345</Reference>
    <Assignment>54321</Assignment>
         <details>
            <Company>HHH</Company>
            <Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>
            <Reference>12345</Reference>
            <Assignment>54321</Assignment>
         </details>
         <details>
              <Company>HHH</Company>
              <Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>
              <Reference>12345</Reference>
               <Assignment>311</Assignment>
         </details>
    </row>
    <row>
     <Company>SSS</Company>
    <Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>
    <Reference>67890</Reference>
    <Assignment>78968</Assignment>
         <details>
            <Company>SSS</Company>
            <Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>
            <Reference>67890</Reference>
            <Assignment>98769</Assignment>
         </details>
  </row>
</root>
```

Current XSL code,
 this only gets the data on the row where posting key is 40. How to check the sibling Posting Key 40 or 15 to output the correct value on the details section?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="root">
<root>
<xsl:for-each-group select="row[Posting_Key='40']" group-by="Reference">
<row>
<xsl:value-of select="Company_Code"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Posting_Key"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Reference"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Assignment"/>
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
<details>
<xsl:value-of select="Company_Code"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Posting_Key"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Reference"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Assignment"/>
</details>
</xsl:for-each>
</row>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this only gets the data on the row where posting key is 40. How to check the sibling Posting Key 40 or 15 to output the correct value on the details section?

Comment: If you want to group all `row` elements by `Reference` then it seems obvious that the `select` of the `for-each-group` should be `select="row"` and not `row[Posting_Key='40']`.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen tried it and the output is not as desired. <Company>HHH</Company>
    <Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>
    <Reference>12345</Reference>
    <Assignment>54321</Assignment> is including in the details.

Comment: It is not clear from the single example which grouping criteria and which aggregration you want to implement, you will need to elaborate on that. And you have the option to show us any result you get in the question. Does the result sample you have shown list the `<Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>` as a child of the `row` and the `<Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>` inside the `details` as that is the order the items occured in the input sample? Or do you want to put any `<Posting_Key>40</Posting_Key>` in the group's `row` container and any `<Posting_Key>15</Posting_Key>`  in the details?

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen I have updated the sample above. Posting key 40 is inside the group's row container and posting key 15 in the details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you rather want to use `group-starting-with` than `group-by`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-starting-with="row[Posting_Key = 40]">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
      <details>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </details>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyL